# Grouping by alias defined in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Why can't I group by "cnt" and have to group by count(*).  This just seems redundant and I wish there was a better way.

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt
from table
group by count(*)
```

Comment: This sentence is not correct: "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.". I don't understant the question. I don't vote down it. But, can you explain?

Comment: Yep. You can't `group by count(*)` that makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the logical processing order of SQL queries. Specifically, the GROUP BY clause is evaluated *before* the SELECT clause, despite appearing at the bottom of the query. Hence, aliases used in the SELECT are not necessarily available to the query processor while it evaluates the logically-precedent parts of the query.

Same reason you can't use aliases in a WHERE clause: that clause is logically processed before the SELECT. ORDER BY, on the other hand, is the last part of the query to be processed - aliases (or even ordinal column positions) *are* typically supported there.

Some implementations may choose to provide this support - see the MySQL link that @daghan posted, for example - but it cannot be relied on; SQL Server, as you can see, doesn't support it.

It's worth pointing out that, were you desperate to refer to a complex expression by an alias, you could perhaps put that expression in a subquery, and refer to it from there. I'd call that overkill in most simple scenarios, though (such as the one in your question).

**Update:** @MartinSmith raises a good point in his comment on the question: aliasing aside, grouping by an aggregate expression isn't going to work. In fact, since the aggregate is determined by a grouping of non-aggregate columns, it doesn't even really make sense. What are you actually trying to achieve with such a query? Perhaps we can help further.

Comment: Related Connect Item: [Column Alias Usage Everywhere in a Query](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/610120)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can use a column alias in any clause other than the `order by` clause in a `select` statement. This is because the the projection list and hence the aliasing in a `select` is evaluated after all other clauses are evaluated and only before `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

The use of alias in the GROUP BY clause may be an extension to the ANSI standard much like using ordinal position and may not be supported by every RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

above might be what you need